# Numerical integration of a Lyapunov differential equation in a kalman filter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, kalman-filter

I'm struggling understanding the following section of the [MSCKF](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Estergios/papers/ICRA07-MSCKF.pdf) paper. This is regarding the covariance matrix propagation of the kalman filter using a continuous-time model.

> $P_{II_{k+1|k}}$ is computed by numerical integration of the Lyapunov equation: $$\dot{P}_{II} = F P_{II} + P_{II} F^T + G Q_{IMU} G^T$$
> Numerical integration is carried out for the time interval (tk, tk +T ), with initial condition $P_{II_{k|k}}$. The state transition matrix Φ(tk + T, tk) is similarly computed by numerical integration of the differential equation
> $$\dot{Φ}(tk + τ, tk) = FΦ(tk + τ, tk), τ ∈ [0, T]$$
> with initial condition $Φ(t_k, t_k) = I_{15}$.

It's the *numerical integration* part that I'm trying to better understand. I found some information [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08327.pdf), but I'm not sure if it applies. Does the fact that it's under the form of a Lyapunov equation help in some way? Any help is kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Numerical integration = Solving an ODE numerically. You can use basically any method for this. RK4 is an easy one to implement that works on many problems. The specific form of the equations doesn't matter for a method like RK4, although there are methods than can exploit problem-specific structures such as symplecticity, linearity, stiffness, etc.